# select data by unix timestamp

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

Below are the table I've created and its records:

```sql
CREATE TABLE students (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  gender TEXT NOT NULL,
  created_at datetime
);

INSERT INTO students VALUES (1, 'Ryan', 'M', '2012-11-03 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO students VALUES (2, 'Joanna', 'F', '2013-11-03 00:00:00');
```

To fetch the records by time, I use the following SQL statement:

```sql
SELECT * FROM students WHERE created_at > 1620489600000;
```

and both records can be returned, which confuses me because 1620489600000 (Sat May 08 2021 16:00:00 GMT+0000) should be a timestamp way later than the create_at fields of both records.

Indeed I know this can also be achieved by specifying a time formatted as `2012-11-03 00:00:00`, but I just wonder:

- whether we can effectively query a `datetime` column in `where` clause with unix timestamp?
- if not, why does the above `select` statement return both records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compare two different data types MySQL automatically converts one of them to the other. In this case it tries to make numbers of the dates. What is the result? See [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3c697/9)

The date gets converted to

```
20121103000000
```

which is bigger than

```
1620489600000
```

So the result in your WHERE clause is true and returns all records.

If you need to go from a Unix Timestamp you could use [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime):

```
WHERE created_at > FROM_UNIXTIME(1620489600000 / 1000)
```

Notice that I divided by 1000 because Unix time [has to be in seconds](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/217744) and not milli seconds.